# Showing only legend items that are actually displayed on map in ArcGIS Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-9.3, legend

Using ArcGIS Desktop, is there a way for the legend, to only show the subitems that are displayed on the map?

Comment: Did you try converting the legend into graphics? After converting into graphics you can manually delete the items in legend that you do not need. I hope that helps. Thanks.

Comment: @Raj - Oh no, I don't plan on doing that maintaining the maps will be pain

Comment: The linked question is another question that has been answered. So ask a new question describing your problem in detail.

Comment: The old question is tagged arcgis 9.3, so you should be OK asking a new question and tagging for ArcGIS 10.  Also, the linked question is an answer and you are asking a troubleshooting question for legend limiter.

Comment: Also, troubleshooting questions can take some time to get traction and you should work to try and keep the question body organized with new information so that it's easy to follow.  Or else other users will look it and move along to the next question.

Comment: I edited my question.  I hope it's clearer now.  Thanks in advance everyone.

Comment: Install in Program Files not 'Program Files (x86)' with admin rights (compatibility mode Windows XP SP3) you can always load the dll into ArcMap Directly via Customise button

Comment: yes, it can done with arcpy, see my answer

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**Legend Limiter**

*The Legend Limiter only works on layers that use "unique value categories" to define symbology. This style of legend can be set up in the Symbology tab of the Layer Properties dialog. Legend Limiter will not limit the symbology of layers set up with single symbol symbology.*

http://arcscripts.esri.com/details.asp?dbid=16097

Comment: That is the closest to what I need, In essence, I have to convert all my symbology to unique value

Comment: @ Mapperz - there's a fix for ArcGIS 10 here: http://forums.arcgis.com/threads/24968-Legend-Limiter-in-Arc-10

Comment: @ Mapperz (or anyone) - I downloaded the necessary files fo Legend Limiter at the link I posted above.  When trying to install, I received an error message, which I googled.  I get the impression that there's no patch in existence making this add-on compatible with both ArcGIS 10 and Windows 7.  On this thread, should I start a new question related to this topic?  Or .... is anyone aware of a patch meeting both parameters (Arc 10 & Windows 7)/

Comment: Run in Windows compability mode on Windows 7.

Comment: @ Mapperz - can you post this answer so I can select it as the answer.  My question on this problem is here:  http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/12609/legend-limiter-will-not-install-to-my-arcview-10-any-suggestions

Comment: An old question but, was looking for same solution for ArcGIS JS Api. So, is there any similar widget to achieve this in JS API?

Comment: In which versions of ArcGIS can Legend Limiter be used? I have ArcGIS 10.0 and cannot find it.  Also, the link provided in 2011 for more instructions no longer is valid.

Comment: @user3386170 Still works https://geonet.esri.com/message/499559?commentID=499559#comment-499559

Comment: I looked at the link above but I still can't figure it out.  Could you provide more details? If I can't find the library "Legendlimiter.dll" in "C://Programme files/ArcGIS/Desktop 10.0/bin", can I still install Legend Limiter?

Answer (score 11):

There is no need to write any additional ArcPy for this.  Simply use [dynamic legends](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//00s900000023000000) (which were added at ArcGIS 10.1) when you are authoring your maps.

> The Map Extent Options allow you to control how eligible legend items
>   interact with the current map extent. If the **Only show classes that
>   are visible in the current map extent** check box is checked, a legend
>   item class will only appear in the legend if a feature from that class
>   is in the current extent. If no features from that legend item are in
>   the current extent, the entire item will be removed from the legend.

Answer (score 4):

In the map view, right-click on the Legend to open the Properties window, then click the "Items" tab. Under "Map Extent Options", select "Only show classes that are visible in the current map extent".

It'll refresh as you move around the map or toggle on/off classes within the layer.

Comment: This seems to be the same as [another answer posted a year earlier](http://gis.stackexchange.com/a/87110/115).

Comment: Thanks for being specific about where the checkbox was hiding!

Answer (score 1):

i think this code will help:

```
import arcpy
import arcpy.mapping
import os
import sys
from arcpy import env
import string


env.workspace = r"C:\Project"
for mxdname in arcpy.ListFiles("*.mxd"):
    print mxdname
    mxd = arcpy.mapping.MapDocument(r"C:\Project\\" + mxdname)
    legend = arcpy.mapping.ListLayoutElements(mxd,"LEGEND_ELEMENT")[0]
    for lyr in legend.listLegendItemLayers():
        legend.updateItem(lyr, use_visible_extent = True)
        print 'updateItem'    
    mxd.save()
del mxd
```