# Legend Limiter will not install to my ArcView 10 - any suggestions?

Tags: arcgis-10.0

In an older version of ArcView, I had an add-on called Legend Limiter for my software.  It would limit the legend categories to ONLY those shown in your map extent.  Say for example, I have a Geology shapefile containing over 100 categories of Geology, but the extent I'm showing on my map only includes 15 categories, this tool will limit my legend to reflect ONLY the categories in my map extent.  It is a great little time saver.

I installed the version found [HERE](http://arcscripts.esri.com/details.asp?dbid=16097).  When I try to run the .exe file however, I get the prompt shown below:

[image: Error Message]

I tried googling the error message number, and the information does not resolve my issue.  I did find a fix for the newer ArcView [HERE](http://forums.arcgis.com/threads/24968-Legend-Limiter-in-Arc-10).  I follow the instructions from the forum to the letter, and when I add the .dll file, it's not recognized (prompt below).

[image]

I am officially out of ideas.  I just can't get it to work.  Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.  Thanks all.

Comment: Mapperz solved this for me at http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/4900/arcgis-in-the-legend-show-legend-items-that-are-only-displayed-on-the-map/4904#comment-16210 (same question answered prior to Windows 7).  Is there a way to merge the questions?  The answer is posted at the link above.