# Updating symbology values/fields shown based on location selection in Data Driven Pages?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, symbology, select-by-location, table-of-contents

I am producing some maps for a client who owns a lot of water and sewer assets. The data supplied by the client has automated symbology which imports when dragging them in from the geodatabase based on unique fields. The number of feature classes is close to 60 and i have gone through and done a select by location based on my Data Driven Pages polygons I've set up, then 'created a layer from selection' for all of these. this helps to improve the performance/speed as it reduces the number of assets down from over 1million to a few thousand just in my areas that need to be mapped (50 x 1:1k maps).

The query I have is that i'm producing a separate 'legend' map which covers all assets that are shown across all the maps. the symbology of each of these feature classes in the table of contents (and therefore legend) doesnt change when i set a definition query or selection query. some of these feature classes are symbolized by up to 3 fields (symbolize by unique features, many fields) and have 20 different symbols, but when i look at the attribute table only 1 of these symbols is present and the remaining 19 are not shown on any of the maps (just as an example of one of them).

Is there a way to automatically update all these feature classes in my table of contents to only show the symbolised features present within my 50 maps?

Answer (score 2):

There is not a way to do this in your Table of Contents but you should be able to restrict it in the Legend of your Layout.

The procedure is described in [Showing only legend items that are actually displayed on map in ArcGIS Desktop?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/4900/showing-only-legend-items-that-are-actually-displayed-on-map-in-arcgis-desktop)

As an aside, when you say:

> The data supplied by the client has automated symbology which imports
>   when dragging them in from the geodatabase based on unique fields.

I think you will find that this may be because that data is coming from feature classes on which subtypes have been defined.

Comment: I had thought "automated symbology" referred to [Representation](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/map/working-with-layers/what-are-representations-.htm)

Comment: @Midavalo I think that is possible too, but I thought I would rule out what I think might be the more common/likely explanation first.  I remember being surprised the first time I saw multiple symbols being used on data that I had dragged and dropped into a map.

Comment: Thanks PolyGeo. Correct sorry, they are subtypes defined in the feature class. however, these subtypes dont appear to be dynamic and still display subtypes that are not present in the data. Because im working in a separate mxd for the legend, i dont believe that the 'showing only legend items that are actually displayed on map' will work for me here?

Comment: I think the same principle will apply except that your "legend map" will need to have "off the page" a data frame of everything that is on any page from your Data Driven Pages.