# Can we insert Legend with only features that are in a shapefile?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.1, legend

I want to insert legend which have 40 labels data, since, the imported symbology have 90 labels, all the labels are getting inserted in the legend.

I do not want to remove them manually from the legend so is there an automated way?

Comment: In layout view? There is an option to only show legend for the items visible in the current map extent if that might help.

Comment: May I know that option?

Comment: @BERA Dynamic Legends only came at 10.1.

Comment: I am using 10.1 version. Could you tell me where can I find this option?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This question is very similar to [Showing only legend items that are actually displayed on map in ArcGIS Desktop?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/4900/showing-only-legend-items-that-are-actually-displayed-on-map-in-arcgis-desktop).

**Dynamic Legends** are what you are looking for
http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//00s900000023000000

[image]